# Best way (if possible) to override npm package's package.json files property

Tags: npm, package.json

I can't find a way to override the package's package.json file. I want to expose more files without having to fork. The package has a *.js, *.min.js, and *.module.js and NPM only downloads the module file because of `"files": [ "lib.module.js" ]`. I've also wanted to expose the src directory in other libraries.